# Передача данных между двумя View

Tags: ios, iphone

Суть такая. Из первого экрана переходим во 2ой экран в нем находится пикер выбираем значение -> возвращаемся. Как получить выбранный элемент в первом View'e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать переменную или свойство, которую видит и View1 и View2. В простейших случаях можно использовать обычную глобальную переменную. Но в духе Obj-C воспользоваться делегатами:

Тогда в любом из ViewController можно получить ссылочку :

```
    GRA_unitedAppDelegate *d = (GRA_unitedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

И обращаться к свойствам как

```
d.myProperty = 1;
```

А можно воспользоваться и механизмом отправки сообщений. При выборе данных из пикера вы отправляете нужные вам данные в виде объекта:

```
- (IBAction) selectButtonPressed:(id)Sender
{
    NSInteger selected = [countrySelect selectedRowInComponent:0];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    Countries *c = (Countries *)[countries objectAtIndex:selected];
    // и отправляем сообщение по инстанциям
    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:VVVcountrySelected object:c];
}
```

А в методе viewDidLoad контроллера View1 регистрируете обработчик это сообщения:

```
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self 
       selector:@selector(countryUpdated:)
           name:VVVcountrySelected
         object:nil];
```

И реализуете сам обработчик:

```
- (void) countryUpdated:(NSNotification *)note
{
    Countries *c = (Countries *)[note object];
//  NSLog(@"Выборка для страны - %@",c.CountryName);
}
```